# jQuery get data from variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I have a variable () loaded with a html code:

```
$.get(url, function (res, data) {
    response = res.responseText;
}
```

The response variable gets loaded with this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="version">1</div>
</body>

</html>
```

how can I retrieve the content of the div#version to a variable version?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want jQuery to parse your result resulting HTML and just retrieve the content of `#version` you can use the following:

```
var response = '<html><head></head><body><div id="version">1</div></body></html>';

var version = $( response ).filter( '#version' ).text();
```

---

**Edit:** Refer to @freakish, whose is the better answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using jQuery and the response **is** html, then you can simply do this:

```
var version = $(res.responseText).find('#version').html();
```

Comment: looks good and accurate. should be `var version` instead of `var r`

Comment: I think that this is more helpful than @Sirko's answer. "filter" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var version = document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;
```

or if you are using jquery then try this -

```
var version = $("#version").text();
```

Comment: This only works when you actually add the HTML to body. I don't think this is what OP wants.